# Calendar DeltaQuerys always result in HTTP 503 or 504 error response

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am using a custom application that uses the Microsoft Graph REST interface.
Through this REST interface I regularly request changed dates using DeltaQuerys.

I have the problem that with some users, the DeltaQuery REST requests always result in an HTTP 503 or 504 error response.
This does not change even if the queries are repeated after waiting for some time or even in the next few days.
The error also occurs if the DeltaQuery query is executed without DeltaToken or SkipToken, it then comes back on the same result page.

Changed appointments can only be queried again after certain mostly daily long-running appointment series with many exception appointments has been deleted.
I do not know what to change in the query.
There is no way to tell which appointment series are causing the problem and need to be deleted.

The last query with this error was this one:

2021-03-23 13:42:03,391 Request:  GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users('...')/calendarview/delta?%24skipToken=aVxnGmD_iauljNDUWJs5WrXLyr_lwnfNiDvP-lcTAFa_UvBvr8wWslITny9WhaMfWACh0-OAnbh3WthBwHwGzHhAIo5vQfyuzaNTzlG4YdIcistSWcGnd_k4woip1k6Lm7IaHAJSYKzh0Sv5R6nBLUNTldsS_Pf7n2yvldImrFNYctGchB7319D8wCbG7MJTp3frgANJ0IesjZemQQq2UYb1x8ZJj7ch9r1SxTURZY3c-yFftH93NMwXTPyjuk0d.DjcXPsqmTgRw_0ygOoRjf891oiOX87OU4iOLpFD_eoc](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users(%27...%27)/calendarview/delta?%24skipToken=aVxnGmD_iauljNDUWJs5WrXLyr_lwnfNiDvP-lcTAFa_UvBvr8wWslITny9WhaMfWACh0-OAnbh3WthBwHwGzHhAIo5vQfyuzaNTzlG4YdIcistSWcGnd_k4woip1k6Lm7IaHAJSYKzh0Sv5R6nBLUNTldsS_Pf7n2yvldImrFNYctGchB7319D8wCbG7MJTp3frgANJ0IesjZemQQq2UYb1x8ZJj7ch9r1SxTURZY3c-yFftH93NMwXTPyjuk0d.DjcXPsqmTgRw_0ygOoRjf891oiOX87OU4iOLpFD_eoc)

Response: HTTP 503 (duration: 23907ms)

```
{   
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-03-23T12:42:03",
      "request-id": "64b1743b-69c4-4602-a282-fd632f256e02",
      "client-request-id": "4f7f37be-ad58-4f75-bc70-16228360b5eb"
    } 
  }
}
```

With kind regards,
Demian

Comment: I would try this. Get the latest delta query (not the previously stored ones, as they're might not reflect the latest changes, thats why you see HTTP 503 error), so you will get the latest delta changes. Now do the changes/implement your business logic.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

My problem is that the HTTP 503 response occurs even with a delta query without a delta token. Some times the HTTP 503 response occurs with a subsequent query with a skip token.

1. calendarView/delta?startDateTime={start}&endDateTime={end} -> HTTP 503
or
1. calendarView/delta?startDateTime={start}&endDateTime={end} -> Result
2. calendarView/delta?$skiptoken=b965... -> Result
3. calendarView/delta?$skiptoken=a124... -> HTTP 503

If this happens it happens with every retry.

Comment: Thanks for the update. In case if you see you such a scenario, try isolate the issue outside of your code - so you can try the same with Graph explorer or POSTMAN as well. Still issue persists then i would suggest you to check with Microsoft support.